# Sharepoint XML owssvr.dll query=*?? How to filter?

Tags: xml, sharepoint

Pretty simple. trying to get XML back from Sharepoint site. Get blank white page...

```
  http://servername/sites/DisasterRecovery/eventmgmt/DRR/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={EEE19336-80D6-42A5-AAA1-F5AF12FA6275}&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

Ok got a little farther

```
http://servername/sites/DisasterRecovery/eventmgmt/DRR/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={EEE19336-80D6-42A5-AAA1-F5AF12FA6275}&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

Returns the entire page of xml data, which still takes some time. is there a way to pass a filter string? Perhaps with the **Query=*** parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can filter with the FilterField1 and FilterValue1 Parameters.
If you need multiple filters, you just need to increase the number at the end.

Example:

```
http://servername/sites/DisasterRecovery/eventmgmt/DRR/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={EEE19336-80D6-42A5-AAA1-F5AF12FA6275}&XMLDATA=TRUE&FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=Test
```

Remember that you have to use the internal field names.

Comment: how can we include all versions to the query?