# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 XML owssvr.dll

Tags: xml, dll, sharepoint-2013

In our 2007 Sharepoint WSS 3.0 site we use owssvr.dll, [as seen in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287983/sharepoint-xml-owssvr-dll-query-how-to-filter), to access our list information as XML.  Is anyone aware if this dll, or some other means, is available in 2013 Foundation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the answer.  Sharepoint 2013 Foundation, which we use, allows use of the the dll for access to list content as xml.  Hope this helps someone!